# Apply "Shares that can be accessed anonymously" without reboot

Tags: windows-10, group-policy, file-sharing

A true anonymous share on modern windows requires listing its name in

```
Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\
  Security Settings\
    Local Policies\
      Security Options\
        Network access: Shares that can be accessed anonymously
```

However, the changes don't take effect until you reboot the PC. I'm using the standalone client tool `smbclient` to eliminate the possibility of existing cached connections affecting the result. For instance, previously I added "INSTALL" to the setting in question and rebooted. After that the following commands succeed:

```
    [root@okvmh1 ~]# smbclient -N //192.168.149.55/INSTALL
    Anonymous login successful
    Try "help" to get a list of possible commands.
    smb: \> ls
      .                                   D        0  Sat Oct  2 13:33:16 2021
      ..                                  D        0  Sat Oct  2 13:33:16 2021
      a                                   D        0  Sat Oct  2 13:33:16 2021

                    121931519 blocks of size 4096. 47507170 blocks available
    smb: \>
```

However, after clearing the setting `smbclient` is still able to connect and access the share and it takes Windows reboot to apply the new setting.

Is it possible to apply the setting immediately? For instance, by restarting some Windows service? I already tried forcing `gpupdate` and restarting `lanmanserver` ("Server"), but it didn't help.

```
C:\>gpupdate /force
C:\>net stop lanmanserver & net start lanmanserver
```

I also tried stopping `SamSs` ("Windows Security Accounts Manager"), but Windows blocks that attempt

Comment: Have you tried restarting the Workstation service `LanmanWorkstation`?

Comment: @PeterHahndorf tried, didn't help